# SQL Server: Rows over 8KB: Where are the docs?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I need to properly understand if and how I can get 10KB or 20KB per row in SQL Server 2016, Standard Edition.

I am reading the SQL Server Tech specs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server#Engine

Specifically "**Bytes per row**"

It refers to something in BOL, that I cannot find.

Where is the section "**Row-Overflow Data Exceeding 8 KB**" topic in SQL Server Books Online. ?

Answer (score 5):

1. [Table and Index Organization](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189051(v=sql.105).aspx)

> Variable length data stored in varchar, nvarchar, varbinary, or
>   sql_variant columns that exceed the 8,060 byte row size limit.
>
> For every partition used by a table (heap or clustered table), index,
>   or indexed view, there is one ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA allocation unit. This
>   allocation unit contains zero (0) pages until a data row with variable
>   length columns (varchar, nvarchar, varbinary, or sql_variant) in the
>   IN_ROW_DATA allocation unit exceeds the 8 KB row size limit. When the
>   size limitation is reached, SQL Server moves the column with the
>   largest width from that row to a page in the ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA
>   allocation unit. A 24-byte pointer to this off-row data is maintained
>   on the original page.

2. [Row-Overflow Data Exceeding 8 KB](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981(v=sql.105).aspx)

> The length of individual columns must still fall within the limit of
>   8,000 bytes for varchar, nvarchar, varbinary, sql_variant, and CLR
>   user-defined type columns. Only their combined lengths can exceed the
>   8,060-byte row limit of a table.

Another good answer here:
[Work around SQL Server maximum columns limit 1024 and 8kb record size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070932/work-around-sql-server-maximum-columns-limit-1024-and-8kb-record-size)

Answer (score 3):

Extents, Pages, and Row overflow data pages are described in the product documentation:

[Pages and Extents Architecture Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/pages-and-extents-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-2017)

> **Large Row Support**
>
> Rows cannot span pages, however portions of the row may be moved off
>   the row's page so that the row can actually be very large. The maximum
>   amount of data and overhead that is contained in a single row on a
>   page is 8,060 bytes (8-KB). However, this does not include the data
>   stored in the Text/Image page type.
>
> This restriction is relaxed for tables that contain varchar, nvarchar,
>   varbinary, or sql_variant columns. When the total row size of all
>   fixed and variable columns in a table exceeds the 8,060-byte
>   limitation, SQL Server dynamically moves one or more variable length
>   columns to pages in the ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA allocation unit, starting
>   with the column with the largest width.

Comment: This question asks _specifically_ for the documentation link, which is out-of-date in the previous answer.